# Have Xcode console output displayed in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, console, output

Is it possible to display the console output from Xcode in the iOS App?
In a UITextView or something else?
Already searched for answers on google & stackoverflow, couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: xcode console displays output of what you have put in NSLOG. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I want to display the output (in realtime) in an UITextView, but how is there NSLog in iOS? Sorry for that q my actual main emphasis is on macOS development

Comment: Try to write this on console: `po textviewName.text` & `po textviewName`